# I need to create a project file for an ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I haven't got a solution file for a project that i have been asked to work on. However i have all the other aspx and aspx.cs files in one location on my comp. Is it possible for me to create a solution file or may be create a new website project in visual studio 2008 so i should be able to compile the website in visual studio.

Alternatively if someone can direct me to a link for setting up a website on IIS would be a great help but bare in mind i dont have a .sln or a .csproj file.

Any Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,
Nitesh.

Comment: Have you tried searching for `setting up a website on iis`? There are lots of results there that can help you.

Comment: If you want to make a new project in visual studio, you can always right click on your project and go to Add-->Existing Item, or you can click show all items, and then right click and include those in your project

Comment: You might not _need_ a project file for the website.  If it was created in Visual Studio as a "website" instead of a "web application" then I don't think there is a project file, just a standard folder structure (including a `bin` folder, etc.).  In short, yes, you can create a project in Visual Studio and add files to it.  But whether or not that's a good idea depends on what you've been given.

Comment: In visual studio if you do File Open Website (and point to the path where the files are), that would provide you all IDE features as it would if you were creating a webproject - "i believe"

Answer (score 1):

You mention that you don't have "a solution file for a project".  Check to see if you have a project file.  If you do, you can just double click that and it will open that project in Visual Studio and place it in a solution.

Just to clarify. A project contains application files (aspx, aspx.cs, .cs etc), and solutions contain projects.

If you don't have a project file, I would create a new empty web application and then "add existing files" to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new website project in VS and then copy your files into it. Use the Show All Files button on Solution Navigator and add them to the project. Should work.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what i did and yes it did work for whoever gets stuck with something stupid like this. I feel bad, sorry about wasting your time guys

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create a new project and then add all of your existing files to it. See [How to: Add Existing Items to a Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Krishna and everyone else, i was being a nut case just opening the website in visual studio and saving it created a solution file which now has automatically configured the site on my comp.